# Active Record save methods throws Cannot visit RSpec::Matchers error

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rspec, matcher

I have this piece of code using ruby and active record

```
customer_email = Email.first(:conditions => {:Email_Address => email_address})
  customer_email.Is_Verified = 1
  customer_email.save!
```

on the line: customer_email.save!, i get an error as follows:

Cannot visit RSpec::Matchers::Matcher (TypeError)

I dont understand why i get this error. I think it has something to do with the column Is_Verified in the Email Table. I am not able to rename this column so i would appreciate any work around.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you `puts customer_email.inspect` before the save?